# Can't select boundary loop with shrink wrap modifier

Tags: edges, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to create a 2d mesh out of a projection of a 3d mesh. My method is to use the shrink wrap modifier and apply it to a plane like so:

[image: Monkey and plane]

[image: Monkey with shrink wrap modifier applied]

This produces a desired look but there are too many verts/tris so I'm trying to create a new mesh by taking the outline of the flattened mesh, I think I am doing something wrong because when I try to select all and select the boundary loop I get the following.

[image: Error in boundary loop on monkey]

Am I going about this the right way? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Don't apply the modifier (yet).  Select your plane and shift numpad 7, then numpad 5 to get an ortho view in the direction of the plane's Z.  Enter edit on your monkey and switch to face select.  Make sure you're not in wireframe or X-ray, then box select the whole monkey, then, select boundary loop.

Comment: In this particular mesh the eyes are both disconnected from the head